# How to hide method from base class in a way `can` do not see it?

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance

I try to hide method from base class by just forward declare subroutine like:

```
sub xid;
```

If I call this method I get expected error:

```perl
DBG> $tuple->xid
ERROR: Undefined subroutine &HyperMouse::Schema::Result::SaldoAnal::xid called at (eval 2346)[/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/site_perl/5.24.1/DB/Hooks.pm:422] line 8, <STDIN> line 13.
```

but `$tuple->can( 'xid' )` still return true value:

```perl
&HyperMouse::Schema::Result::SaldoAnal::xid
```

How can I hide `xid` method, so `$tuple->can( 'xid' )` return false instead of:

```
&HyperMouse::Schema::Result::SaldoAnal::xid
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override `can`.

Hide all existing-but-undefined subs:

```perl
sub can {
   my $self = shift;
   my $cv = $self->SUPER::can(@_)
      or return undef;
   defined(&$cv)
      or return undef;
   return $cv;
}
```

Hide a specific sub:

```perl
sub can {
   my $self = shift;
   my $cv = $self->SUPER::can(@_)
      or return undef;
   $cv == \&xid
      and return undef;
   return $cv;
}
```

Your whole attempt to hide a method of the base class is a very strange thing to do. Causing the call to fail would be less surprising.

```perl
sub xid {
   croak("Not supported.");
}
```

But that doesn't really hide the stink of poor class design.

Whichever hack you use, it's entirely bypassable using

```perl
$tuple->Base::Class::xid()
```

Comment: Where do you do check for `xid` in your `sub can` example?

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, `defined(&$cv)` checks for (existing but) undefined subs (such as `xid`) in general. (Oops, it didn't handle non-existent methods. Fixed.) Added an alternative that filters by name.

Answer (score 4):

`can` works because the method name is still present in your class's symbol table, but it points to undef. You have to write your own override for `can`.

```
sub can {
  my($self) = shift;
  my($method) = @_;

  return undef if $method == "xid";
  return $self->SUPER::can($method);
}
```

However, this means your subclass now violates its base class's interface, it does not behave like the base object. This indicates poor design. Consider a different approach, subclassing may be inappropriate. Try composition instead.

Comment: This implementation of `can` will break a subclass that implements `xid`.

Comment: @ikegami True. Is that a bug or a feature? Depends on why it's being done. The whole idea is kinda screwy.

Comment: yeah. Not suggesting a change; just making a note of it.

Comment: I accept @ikegami, because his answer has more examples and explanations. I need to hide method, because objects could be with old or new design. I do not want some methods from old class be visible in new interface. So this hiding is only for migration period.